# .NET Core 2 - Web Api - Azure AD - User is NULL

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, .net-core, azure-active-directory

I have a .NET Core 2.1 Web API application in which I have Azure AD set up for authentication. For my authorization I'm using an `AuthorizationHandler` that does some validation based on the user name. The problem I'm running into is that the `User.Identity.Name` always returns `null` and I'm not sure why.

Here's my `Startup.cs` where I have the Authentication and Authorization set up :

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
   if (env.IsDevelopment())
   {
      app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
   }
   else
   {
     app.UseHsts();
   }

   app.UseCors("AllowAnyOrigin");

   app.UseAuthentication();

   app.UseMvc();     
}

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   // Azure AD
   services.AddAuthentication(
         sharedOptions =>
         {
          sharedOptions.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
          sharedOptions.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
          })
          .AddJwtBearer(
            options =>
              {
                options.Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + "MyTenant";
                options.Audience = "MyClientId";
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                  ValidIssuer = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + "MyTenant" +"/v2.0";
                };
          });

     services.AddAuthorization(
            options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("MyPolicy", policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new NameRequirement());
            });

     services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, NameRequirementHandler>();

     services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("AllowAnyOrigin",
                builder => builder
                .AllowAnyOrigin()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader());
        });

      services.Configure<MvcOptions>(options => {
            options.Filters.Add(new CorsAuthorizationFilterFactory("AllowAnyOrigin"));
        });



     services.AddMvc()
     .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
}
```

In my my `AuthorizationHandler` I want to get the name of the authenticated user in order to do some validation on it. I can see the Bearer token in the Request however the `User.Identity.Name` and all of the claims are `null`.

```
public class NameRequirementHandler : AuthorizationHandler<NameRequirement>
{
    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, NameRequirement requirement)
    {
        var authorizationFilterContext = context.Resource as AuthorizationFilterContext;
        if (authorizationFilterContext != null)
        {
            HttpContext httpContext = authorizationFilterContext.HttpContext;
            string userName = httpContext.User.Identity.Name; // ALWAYS NULL

           //Do some validation here with the user name value
        }

        context.Succeed(requirement);

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Currently I have a really simple Controller that I'm using to test the Authentication and Authorization:

```
[Authorize(Policy = "MyPolicy")]
public class ValuesController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
}
```

What am I missing in order to populate the user information from the Bearer token? To add a little more context, I'm porting this over from .NET Framework and it works there but it uses the extension method `UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication` which doesn't exist in .NET Core

Here's what it looks like in .NET Framework

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
   var tokenValidation = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidAudience = "https://graph.windows.net/"
        };

        var authOptions = new WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions
        {
            Tenant = "MyTenant",
            TokenValidationParameters = tokenValidation,
            MetadataAddress = ""
        };

        app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication(authOptions);
}
```

I've seen other questions posted and read many articles but still haven't been able to get this to work. What part of my configuration is wrong?

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATED**

I ended up finding the solution to this issue, the audience value was incorrectly set. I was not setting the value of the audience that the token's "aud" value. You can go to https://jwt.ms to see the claims of the token and make sure the right audience is set.

Comment: How did you test your project? Have you login before hitting `NameRequirementHandler`? I made a test with built-in AAD authenticaiton template, but fail to reproduce your issue. Please check how to reproduce your issue based on [AspNetCoreAAD](https://github.com/Edward-Zhou/AspNetCore/blob/21170f1df0c39abdc42396843956ef76e645d858/AspNetCoreAAD/StartupAADCustom.cs#L42).

Comment: I'm testing it from an angular application that makes the call to the controller. It calls the endpoint with the bearer token after logging in with the users AD account.

Thank you for the sample application. I tried it and it worked for me as well, however when I moved it to my application it doesn't work. Could it be because the sample application is an MVC  web application and mine is a Web API microservice with docker support?

Comment: Could you share us a demo which could reproduce your issue? To check whether it is related with docker, I suggest you remove docker support for a try.

Comment: Try to set the `NameClaimType = JwtClaimTypes.Name` and 
`RoleClaimType = JwtClaimTypes.Role`  when initializing the `TokenValidationParameters` object. Additionally read this post [Missing Claims in the ASP.NET Core 2 OpenID Connect Handler?](https://leastprivilege.com/2017/11/15/missing-claims-in-the-asp-net-core-2-openid-connect-handler/)

Comment: @TaoZhou I was finally able to get it to work when calling the endpoint in the browser. 

There's a problem now when trying to call the endpoint from a different application with a different host, it produces the error:

`Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://login.microsoftonline.com`

I have CORS set up in my `Startup.cs` to allow any origin, any header, and any method so not sure why this is happening.

Comment: Did you define the CORS in the project which defining the endpoint? Share us the related configuration.

Comment: @TaoZhou Yes, in the Web Api project with the `ValuesController` I have the following in the `Startup.cs`. I updated my question with the CORS configuration. Thanks.

Comment: Try to add `.AllowCredentials();` to `AddCors` and have you sent token from js client?

Comment: Added `AllowCredentials()` after `AllowAnyHeader()` but still getting the same errors:

`Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access`

`Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8082/api/values. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).`

In the js client I can see the token being acquired, and see the value of the token, but when trying to hit the Web API it gives the errors.

Comment: When I use Postman to make the call to the endpoint and I add the Authorization header with the token I get a `302` response:

HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Location: https://login.microsoftonline.com/45d659f4.....
Server: Kestrel

Comment: Have you solved your issue? I have the same issue as well and cannot find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call UseAuthentication in the Configure method where you have access to IApplicationBuilder. It'll be something like this,

```
// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
    loggerFactory.AddDebug();

    app.UseAuthentication(); // Make sure you've done this!

    app.UseMvc();
}
```

From the documentation, "Adds the AuthenticationMiddleware to the specified IApplicationBuilder, which enables authentication capabilities."

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.authappbuilderextensions.useauthentication?view=aspnetcore-2.0

Comment: I made sure to have `app.UseAuthentication()` in my `Configure()` method, I put the sample code in my question. I'm still seeing the issue.